How to execute concurrent void method calls
I'm working with a database and trying to figure out how I can concurrently execute writes which have a void return type. I've already wrapped the blocking calls as per the docs.
I want to:

Get the item from the database which returns a Mono<ObjectToReturn>
Concurrently call 2 methods which return Mono<Void> which I need to complete before I return
Return the response from get() to the subscriber

Functionally I have this working with:
    return repository
            .get(param)
            .flatMap(response -> Mono.zip(
                    method1(response),
                    method2(response),
                    (x, y) -> response
            ))

However:

I feel like I'm abusing Mono.zip to subscribe to the response since I'm ignoring x and y

I've had to change the method1/2 interfaces to arbitrarily return a value after the write is successful


What's the right way of doing this?

The problem with your code is that if any mono is empty, the zip operation won't emit any value, resulting in no output.
I think it is better to use .thenReturn() fallback:
 return repository.get(param)
                  .flatMap(response -> Mono.zip(method1(response), method2(response))
                        .thenReturn(response)
                  )

The response will be returned after Mono.zip is completed

thanks that's exactly what I needed. I thought the zip interface required the 3rd parameter.

I'll change the method1/2 interface to return Mono<Optional> to at least emit a response instead of null, and tell the caller there is no response value. I'm happy with this solution but wondered if there's a cleaner way to do this?
